# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Node.js Selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium

So i have this little script:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/?hl=lt&gl=LT');
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("load-more-text']"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

it supposed to open firefox go to youtube and scroll to bottom of the screen where the load more button is. But it throws syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to change this line

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.class("load-more=text']"));
```

as

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("load-more-text"));
```

because class name `load-more=text']` more likely to be `load-more-text` and AFAIK there is no `By.class`, but `By.className`

Comment: sorry for those typos i changed hem but still get same error console underlines those js letters at 3rd line of code

Comment: You mean this line `JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;`?

Comment: if you made copy/paste of this line from net, try to retype it manually as sometimes it contains some hidden characters

Comment: i rewrited all script dont understand whats wrong :(